# Regex - Finding fullstops (periods) that aren't followed by a space

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a simple Grammar correction tool.

I want to create a regular expression that finds *fullstops* (" **.** ") that **are not** followed by a *space* so I can replace that with a fullstop and space.

For e.g. `This is a sentence.This is another sentence.`

Only the **first fullstop** in the above example should be matched in the expression.

I've tried `/\.[^\s]/g` but it returns an additional character after the matched fullstop. I would like to match only the fullstop.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negated character class `[^\s]` in the pattern expects a match (any character except a whitespace character), that is why you have the additional character.

If you want to match the dot only, you could use a negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not a whitspace char or the end of the string:

```
\.(?!\s|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gE3bcg/1)

---

To not match a dot that is not followed by a whitespace char excluding a newline:

```
\.(?![^\S\r\n])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P9NcsW/1)

Comment: A small side issue is that new lines after non-spaced fullstops do not get recognized. For eg. 

1. End of word.New word.  <--- This matches as intended.

2. End of word.\nNew word.  <--- This does not

If it helps, I'm working inside a contenteditable div where the \n character doesn't even show up.

Comment: @karjedavpalaa Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/KmHmBa/1

Comment: I had a look at the example but it's not working on regex101.com either.

Comment: @karjedavpalaa You can match both dots like this https://regex101.com/r/P9NcsW/1

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Thefourthbird it matches end of line dots in some use cases as you're caring more detailed than needed, in regex, more words you write, less effective could be:
https://regex101.com/r/P9NcsW/2

Comment: @JoelBonetR In the previous comment the OP want to match a dot at the end of the line. It should not match if it is followed by a whitespace. This part `[^\S\r\n]` matches a whitespace char without a carriage return or newline .

Comment: Oh ok, don't take the point on replacing an EOL dot with dot + space but... xD

Answer (score 1):

You can look for all dots using:

```
(\.)
```

This will match all dots on below examples:

This is a sentence.This is another sentence.

i am looking. for dots. . ...

You can add a  |$ to seek for end of line, and with a little tweak, you get a regex that match all dots not followed by whitespace nor being on the end of a line:

```
(\.(?!\ |$))
```

Note that there's a whitespace as literal here. The "must-work-everywhere" example will be like:

```
(\.(?![[:space:]]|$))
```

If not, search on the regex reference on the language you use.

[image: Regex test]

Comment: You don't have to escape the space and you can omit the capturing group around the pattern. +1